# establishing connection between two apps models and using them interchangebly

Tags: python, html, django-models

I ran into a runtime error problem when I tried retrieving data from my base app vehicles model and displaying it in my new client app views and rendering it in a template

I tried using django extensions to connect the two app models and the calling the data from the database directly but it did not work

```
 def display_vehicles(request):
    vehicles = Vehicles.objects.first()  
    #vehicles = [order.vehicles for order in vehicles]
   return render(request, 'client/vehicle.html',{'vehicles':vehicles})

html file
{% for vehicle in vehicles  %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{vehicle.vehicleType }}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.numberPlate}}</td>
        <td> {% if vehicle.vehicle_image %}
          <img src="{{vehicle.vehicle_image.url}}" width="200">
          {% endif %} 
        </td>
       
        <td>
          {% if vehicle.status == 'Booked' %}
          <p>Booked</p>
          {% else %}
          <p>Available</p>
          {% endif %} 
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="item1"></td>
    </tr>
    {%  endfor %}
```